# javascript variable doesn't show validation errors of codeigniter in the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, validation

i'm using ci built-in validation_errors() function in my login form.
everything works fine and i can see true validation errors in my view.
but when i echo validation errors into my js variable in the script to show it in the customized notifications, nothing shows.
here is my code:

```
    <?php if (isset($validation_error)){
        echo $validation_error;} ?>
    <script>
        var text=  "<?php echo $validation_error;?>";
    </script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>resources/js/assets/errore-not.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
```

when i pass any php variables or strings in "text" variable of script, it shows the notification correctly.
this is my notify code:

```
$(document).ready(function notification () {
    $.notify({
        icon: "notifications",
        message: text

    }, {
        type: 'danger',
        timer: 4000,
        placement: {
            from: 'top',
            align: 'center'
        }
    });
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: <script>
        var text= $validation_error;
    </script> here you allocate php variable without php tag to javascript variable...

Comment: i've been used this mechanism to show upload errors of ci  in exactly this way and it works fine.the return value of this function:  $this->upload->display_errors() @Teemu

Comment: The original source code was `var text= $validation_error;` which certainly won't work. Later you've edited the code to a working version.

Comment: In Firebug or on chrome inspect, are you getting any errors or warnings?

Comment: To test your $.notify call just hard-code message: 'my temp text' and check if its working. If its not wroking then you have check notify call first

Comment: i've checked it and it works @MangeshSathe

Comment: yes this is the error:jQuery.Deferred exception: text is not defined ReferenceError: text is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.notification. @MangeshSathe

Comment: if hard-cded text is working then Check the scope of the text variable by using alert() call, check scope on  where it is alerting and where it is not

Comment: checked it and unfortunately there is no scope which text has been defined in it @MangeshSathe

Comment: try this, change message: text to message:'<?php echo $validation_error;?>' also check by using doublw quote, initialize message directly form PHP and not through Javascript variable

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the php variable value inside javascript variable like this.

```
<?php if (isset($validation_error)){
    echo $validation_error; ?>
<script>
    var text= '<?php echo $validation_error;?>';
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: tnx but my code was like this before and it didn't work for me.